# Unable to parse json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json which i'm trying to parse it using javascript. Iteration count and the pages getting appended to it are going to be dynamic.

***Expected Result***

[image: iteration]

Just like the above image i'm able to take dynamic iteration keys from the below mentioned json.

***Iteration.json***

```
{
    "count":[
    {
    "iteration1":[
    {
    "PageName":"T01_Launch"
    },
    {
    "PageName":"T02_Login"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "iteration2":[
    {
    "PageName":"T01_Launch"
    },
    {
    "PageName":"T02_Login"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
}
```

When i click on iteration it has to populate the corresponding pagenames for that particular iteration as shown in **expected result image**. But what i get actually is (refer the image below):

[image: iteration2]

Please find the code that i tried:

```
     var pagenamearray = [];

$.getJSON("iteration.json", function(json) {
    var hits = json.count;

    var iterations, tnname, iteration;

    for (var k in hits) {
        var value;
        if (hits.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            value = hits[k];
            var iteratearray = [];

            for (var j in value) {

                if (value.hasOwnProperty(j)) {

                    j;

                    var check = value[j];

                    for (var i in check) {

                        if (check.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

                            var test = check[i];

                            for (var t in test) {

                                if (test.hasOwnProperty(t)) {


                                    var pagename = JSON.stringify(t)


                                    var arr = []
                                    if (pagename.includes("PageName")) {


                                        //alert("Key is " +pagename + ", value is" + JSON.stringify(test[t]));

                                        for (var it = 0; it < hits.length; it++) {

                                            if ((Object.keys(hits[it])).includes(j)) {
                                                var pagenamevalue = test[t];
                                                arr[it] = [];
                                                arr.push(pagenamevalue);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    //alert(arr)

                                }
                                pagenamearray.push(arr);

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                var row = document.createElement('div');
                row.setAttribute("class", "row");
                row.setAttribute("id", j)

                var gridWidth = document.createElement('div');
                gridWidth.setAttribute("class", "col-lg-12");

                var panelRoot = document.createElement('div');
                panelRoot.setAttribute("class", "panel panel-default");

                var panelHeading = document.createElement('div');
                panelHeading.setAttribute("class", "panel-heading");

                var heading3 = document.createElement('a');
                heading3.setAttribute("class", "panel-title");

                var icon = document.createElement('i');
                icon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw");

                heading3.appendChild(icon);
                heading3.innerHTML = j;
                heading3.setAttribute("onclick", "doit('" + j + "');");

                panelHeading.appendChild(heading3);
                /*        var panelBody=document.createElement('div');
                        panelBody.setAttribute("class","panel-body");
                        panelBody.setAttribute("id","panellinks");*/

                panelRoot.appendChild(panelHeading);
                //     panelRoot.appendChild(panelBody)
                gridWidth.appendChild(panelRoot);
                row.appendChild(gridWidth);
                document.getElementById("analysis").appendChild(row);




            }


        }


    }

});

function doit(value) {
    var ul = document.getElementById(value);
    if (ul != undefined) {
        $("#" + "expandlinks").remove();
        $("#" + value + value).remove();
    }

    var accordion = document.getElementById(value);

    var panelBody = document.createElement('div');

    panelBody.setAttribute("class", "panel-body");
    panelBody.setAttribute("id", "expandlinks")

    var tablediv = document.createElement('div')
    var tablelink = document.createElement('a');
    tablediv.appendChild(tablelink);
    var graphdiv = document.createElement('div')
    var graphlink = document.createElement('a');
    graphdiv.appendChild(graphlink);
    var recommndiv = document.createElement('div');
    var recommendlink = document.createElement('a');
    recommndiv.appendChild(recommendlink)

    //alert(pagenamearray.length)
    tablelink.innerHTML = pagenamearray;
    /*graphlink.innerHTML="Timeline View";
    recommendlink.innerHTML="Recommendations";*/
    panelBody.appendChild(tablediv);

    panelBody.appendChild(recommndiv);
    panelBody.appendChild(graphdiv);
    accordion.appendChild(panelBody);


}
```

Any advise on how to achieve this would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your `json` example :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how you assign the `pagenamearray` to `tablelink.innerHTML`. This converts the array to a string, converting all elements in the array to a string too and separating them by a comma each. However, your `pagenamearray` contains some empty arrays too; these will convert to an empty string in the process, but will still have a comma before and after them.

In your example code above, the `pagenamearray` will end up with a value of `[[[],"T01_Launch"],[[],"T02_Login"],[null,[],"T01_Launch"],[null,[],"T02_Login"]]` - when converted to a String, this will result in `",T01_Launch,,T02_Login,,,T01_Launch,,,T02_Login"`. So instead of assigning it to the innerHTML value directly, you'll first have to filter out the empty arrays and null values.